# How can I wrap a bootstrap row with an href element that's produced from twitch.tv's API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I just made a json/javascript project for Free Code Camp that pulls streamer information such as their logo, current status, and display name.

I want to wrap entire bootstrap 3 rows in hyperlinks that have the streamers links so you don't have to click on the display status or logo.

https://codepen.io/mmcphillips/pen/qjyZxv

Currently I have the logo and status wrapped in hyperlinks that I got from

```
   $.getJSON(url,function(status1){
if(status1.status===null){
  $("#liveStatus1").html("Offline");
}
else{
  $("#liveStatus1").html("<a href="+status1.url+">"+status1.status+"</a>");
  $("#drRow").html("<a href="+status1.url+"></a>");
}
console.log(status1.url);
```

});

I tried to do this with my second else statement in the code sample and the entire row in the status1.url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$("#liveStatus1")` is your link inside the row, and `$('#drRow')` is your row, try this:

```
//when clicking the row, trigger the link inside
$('#drRow').click(function(){
    $("#liveStatus1").click();
});

//stop propagation of the event to prevent infinite recursion
$("#liveStatus1").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

let me know

Comment: #livestatus was just one of the heading IDs, but this explained exactly what I was looking for. This is great thank you